# How do I create a crowdsale smart contract that has maximum buy amount

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, truffle-contract, crowdsale

I wrote a code for a crowdsale smart contract. Code is below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.0;

contract Context {
    constructor () internal { }
    // solhint-disable-previous-line no-empty-blocks

    function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    function TokensPurchased(address buyer, uint256 amount) external  returns (bool success);
    function burn(uint256 _value) external returns (bool success);
}

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        uint c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint c = a - b;

        return c;
    }
    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint) {
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint c = a / b;

        return c;
    }
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}

library Address {
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != 0x0 && codehash != accountHash);
    }
}

library SafeERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    using Address for address;

    function safeTransfer(IERC20 token, address to, uint value) internal {
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transfer.selector, to, value));
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(IERC20 token, address from, address to, uint value) internal {
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transferFrom.selector, from, to, value));
    }

    function safeApprove(IERC20 token, address spender, uint value) internal {
        require((value == 0) || (token.allowance(address(this), spender) == 0),
            "SafeERC20: approve from non-zero to non-zero allowance"
        );
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, value));
    }
    function safeIncreaseAllowance(IERC20 token, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        uint256 newAllowance = token.allowance(address(this), spender).add(value);
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, newAllowance));
    }

    function safeDecreaseAllowance(IERC20 token, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        uint256 newAllowance = token.allowance(address(this), spender).sub(value, "SafeERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, newAllowance));
    }
    function callOptionalReturn(IERC20 token, bytes memory data) private {
        require(address(token).isContract(), "SafeERC20: call to non-contract");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = address(token).call(data);
        require(success, "SafeERC20: low-level call failed");

        if (returndata.length > 0) { // Return data is optional
            // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
            require(abi.decode(returndata, (bool)), "SafeERC20: ERC20 operation did not succeed");
        }
    }
}

contract ReentrancyGuard {
    bool private _notEntered;

    constructor () internal {
        
        _notEntered = true;
    }

    
    modifier nonReentrant() {
        // On the first call to nonReentrant, _notEntered will be true
        require(_notEntered, "ReentrancyGuard: reentrant call");

        // Any calls to nonReentrant after this point will fail
        _notEntered = false;

        _;

        
        _notEntered = true;
    }
}

contract presale is Context, ReentrancyGuard{
    
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    address public governance;
    
    uint256 public rate;
    uint256 private _weiRaised;
    uint256 public totalSold;
    IERC20 public tokenAddress;
    //uint256 public startTime = 1607407761; //
    //uint256 public endTime = 1608407761; //
    
    uint256 public minimumBuyAmount = 10 ** 17;
    uint256 public maximumBuyAmount = 30*10**18;
    address payable public walletAddress;
    event TokensPurchased(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    
    constructor () public {
        governance = tx.origin;
        rate = uint256(50);
        walletAddress = 0xB3fA96b68A4e0C4AC358FE6BeE3620C787651256; //MultiSender 0x383f7CC1124c255b9DD71F8f8A41c08C10480C1a //TEAM Ropsten 0x30D095D6f0043C9030a545A3B7cFAAE738F44de5
        tokenAddress = IERC20(0x0); // AmpleForth 0x0c14d945Df4a2A5606490b363ccA33e3b7043706 //0xf62A0f785C28d18774Df1d07A555A68336a5c16E
    }
    
    function () external payable {
        buy();
    }
    
    function changeWallet (address payable _walletAddress) public {
        require(msg.sender == governance, "!governance");
        walletAddress = _walletAddress;
    }
    
    function setToken(IERC20 _tokenAddress) public {
        require(msg.sender == governance, "!governance");
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }
    
    function buy() public payable {
        //require((block.timestamp > startTime ) && (block.timestamp < endTime)  , "D01 Token Crowdsate is not active");
        uint256 weiValue = msg.value;
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        require((weiValue >= minimumBuyAmount) &&(weiValue<= maximumBuyAmount), "Minimum amount is 0.1 eth and Maximum amount is 30 Eth");
        uint256 senderBal = token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require((senderBal < maximumBuyAmount.mul(rate)), "You can only buy maximum of 30 Eth worth of tokens");
        uint256 amount = weiValue.mul(rate);
        _weiRaised = _weiRaised.add(weiValue);   
        token.safeTransfer(msg.sender, amount);
        walletAddress.transfer(weiValue);
        //require(walletAddress.send(weiValue)); //_fundRaisingWallet.transfer(msg.value);
        //require(token.TokensPurchased(msg.sender, amount));
        totalSold += amount;
        emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, amount);
    }
    
    function burnUnsold() public {
        require(msg.sender == governance, "!governance");
        //require((block.timestamp > endTime), "D01 Token Crowdsate is still active");
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        token.burn(amount);
    }
    
}
```

So in the function `buy()` I tried to implement a situation whereby the code first checks how many tokens the buyer has bought. The maximum buy amount is 30 ETH. If the buyer hasn't bought up to 30 ETH , It will allow him to buy more up to a max of 30 ETH worth of tokens.

This mechanism is put in place to prevent one person from buying all the tokens.

When I deployed the smart contract to Ganache, I Also deployed the token contract to Ganache with max supply of 45k. Then I sent 35,000 tokens to the crowdsale smart contract. I used one of my accounts on ganache to send 29 ETH to the smart contract but it throws an error. But when I sent only 1 ETH to the smart contract it is successful and I received 50 of the tokens. Then if I try to send another 1 ETH from the same address it throws an exception.

First the code for the buy function was like this:

```
require((senderBal < maximumBuyAmount), "You can only buy maximum of 30 Eth worth of tokens");
```

Then it was throwing an exception for the second time I want to buy from same account.
But then I changed it to:

```
require((senderBal < maximumBuyAmount.mul(rate)), "You can only buy maximum of 30 Eth worth of tokens");
```

Thinking the problem was that, since the maximum buy amount is 30 ETH this will be equivalent to `30 * 10^18` and since the token is also using a decimal of 18. Then 30 ETH will be equivalent to 30 of the tokens. So I had to modify the code to account for this by multiplying `maximumBuyAmount` by the `rate`

`maximumBuyAmount.mul(rate)`

I re-deployed the smart contract and repeated the step but it still throws an exception the second time of trying to send ETH to the smart contract from the same address.

Comment: To convert from wei to tokens the function uses the formula: `uint256 amount = weiValue.mul(rate);` then to obtain weis from tokens it should divide `senderBal.div(rate)` give the amout purchased. So the check `require(senderBal < maximumBuyAmount.mul(rate), "...");` should work. Are you sure the error is there? the code seems correct to me.

Comment: I think the problem is from Ganache. I deployed it to a public test network and it's working fine.